# Crystal Reports / concatenating rows based on change in repeated field value

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, concatenation, crystal-reports-2008, transpose

I have been pulling my hair out on this one.  I'm not very adept at coding formulas.

I have a two column database that looks like this:

```
USERID1     1/1/2000
USERID1     2/1/2000
USERID1     3/3/2001
USERID2     1/5/2000
USERID2     2/7/2001
USERID2     3/30/2009
USERID2     3/10/2013
USERID3     2/5/2000
USERID3     3/7/2001
USERID3     5/30/2009
USERID3     9/10/2013
```

I think I need something to step through all of the rows that relate to `USERID1` and write them all to one row:

`USERID1     1/1/2000 2/1/2000 3/3/2001`

Then move to the next `USERID` Value and write the associated dates:

`USERID2     1/5/2000 2/7/2001 3/30/2009 3/10/2013`

As seen above, the total number of records for each `USERID` value is different.

The results can be concatenated with commas, or separate fields.

I have tried using the "multiple columns" option in Section Expert, and have tried various concatenation formulas, but can't get the right syntax for the data types, and haven't seen how to loop through column A and change an array input when the value changes in column a.

Comment: What database platform are you using? There is the listagg function in Oracle: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20602/oracle-listagg-forces-sort-group-by-execution-plan

Answer (score 3):

Add a group on `USERID`.

Add this formula to the group's header section and suppress it:

```
// {@reset}
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array reset;
StringVar Array dates:=reset;
True; // return a dummy value
```

Add this formula to the detail section and suppress it:

```
// {@serialize}
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array dates;

Redim Preserve dates[Ubound(dates)+1];
dates[Ubound(dates)]:=ToText({table.date_field,"MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Add this formula to the group's footer section:

```
//{@display}
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar Array dates;
Join(dates, ",");
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, I really appreciate the response.

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports 11.5 and everything looks good except for @reset, I get a pop up saying that the "result of a formula cannot be an array"